# inflate options menu without xml

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I am trying to add items to options menu of `Activity` from a module. But if there is no options menu, I want to inflate my own menu. If I declare `xml` in module, it says that resource not found. So maybe there is some way to inflate menu without layout file?

I mean `getMenuInflater().inflate(id, menu);`

**EDIT**:

No answer was what I asked for, so I will try to specify my question. In case there is no `onOptionsMenuCreated` (I check it via `reflections`), I need to inflate my custom menu into `Activity` from module. How can I do it?

Comment: Did you tried cleaning using Project->Clean ? What is the logcat output?

Comment: It is the same. I assume it is searching for resource in project, not in library. But I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

Inflating implies converting XML file to Java object. no such thing as inflating without XML file. However, you could create the menu using the java code for example like this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, R.string.title_about);
    menuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_about);
    ...
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The menu can be created using both xml and java code. To add menu items via code you would use something like the following

```
@Override  
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
    menu.add("Add")  
    .setIcon(R.drawable.menu_add)  
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);  
    return true;  
}
```

Comment: how do you know "Add" was clicked? I mean it doesn't have id

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override  
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menubn) {  
    menubn.add("Add");  
    menubn.setIcon(R.drawable.menuoption);  
    menubn.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);  

}
```

Comment: how do you know "Add" was clicked? I mean it doesn't have id